# Restrict some Organizations Permissions on a specific OU in AWS IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-organizations

With the new `Organizations:CloseAccount` permission in AWS IAM. I am trying to create a rôle which is only allowed to close account in a specific OU.
I tried many things in the `Ressources` field. But I can't find the correct way. It seems to only accept an organization ID and not ou ID.

To be more precise I have an account in the root/management account. I want to allow him to only close accounts in a specific OU freely but deny close accounts from other OU.

Thanks

EDIT : I add some precisions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your AWS Organization [create a Service Control Policy (SCP)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps_create.html) that denies all users and roles to call that  `Organizations:CloseAccount` action - except the one in the Condition (`name-of-admin-role-to-allow`).
2. Then [attach it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps_attach.html) to the specific OU.

What is a SCP?

> An SCP defines a guardrail, or sets limits, on the actions that the
> account's administrator can delegate to the IAM users and roles in the
> affected accounts. The administrator must still attach identity-based
> or resource-based policies to IAM users or roles, or to the resources
> in your accounts to actually grant permissions. The effective
> permissions are the logical intersection between what is allowed by
> the SCP and what is allowed by the IAM and resource-based policies.
> [Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html)

Example

```
{    
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyAccountCloseWithException",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "Organizations:CloseAccount",
        "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
        "iam:DeleteRole",
        "iam:DeleteRolePermissionsBoundary",
        "iam:DeleteRolePolicy",
        "iam:DetachRolePolicy",
        "iam:PutRolePermissionsBoundary",
        "iam:PutRolePolicy",
        "iam:UpdateAssumeRolePolicy",
        "iam:UpdateRole",
        "iam:UpdateRoleDescription"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam::*:role/name-of-role-to-deny"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalARN":"arn:aws:iam::*:role/name-of-admin-role-to-allow"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply. I think, I was not very clear, sorry. 
Basically I have one role in the management account. What I am trying to do it's to let that role to delete accounts which are in a specific OU and deny deletion attempts on every other accounts outside of this OU.